# Grid Conditionals

Tags: conditionals, grid

I have a grid field set up for social links. The first column selects the network, the second field a link. I'd like to have a conditional working so it tests against the content and adds corresponding classes:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="social" disable="category_fields|member_data|pagination" limit="1"}{social_links}
<li class="{if {social_links:network}=="Google"}google{/if}">Our <a href="{social_links:network_url}">{social_links:network}</a></li>
<li class="{if {social_links:network}=="Twitter"}google{/if}">Follow us on <a href="{social_links:network_url}">{social_links:network}</a></li>
<li class="{if {social_links:network}=="Facebook"}google{/if}">Join us on <a href="{social_links:network_url}">{social_links:network}</a></li>
{/social_links}{/exp:channel:entries}
```

I'd also like to be able to test if a grid field is empty like:

**{if social_links!=""}Do something {if:else} or do this{/if}**

Any ideas?

Comment: I've also tried:  {if social_links:network=="Google"}google{/if} - but this had no effect either.

Comment: Have you tried class="{if '{social_links:network}' == 'Google'}google{/if}"

Comment: @JeanSt-Amand you ought to make that a statement and put it as an answer. I think it'll solve the problem. Point out the importance of the single and double quotes. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd recommend trying class="{if '{social_links:network}' == 'Google'}google{/if}"

Whatever you use for the conditional, if you match up the quotes usage (double versus single), it makes a big difference.

Comment: You're very welcome!