# If statement parentheses not working correctly

Tags: ifelse

I've got a weird issue with parentheses in an if statement. If I have the if statement on it's own then no content is shown. If, however, I place two if statements in front of it then everything works fine. See examples below:

Works

```
{if downloads:total_rows >= '1'}{/if}
{if section_1:total_rows == '1'}{/if}
{if (downloads:total_rows >= '1' || section_2:total_rows == '1') && section_1:total_rows == '1'}
    Content ...
{/if}
```

Does not work

```
{if (downloads:total_rows >= '1' || section_2:total_rows == '1') && section_1:total_rows == '1'}
    Content ...
{/if}
```

Does anyone know why this strange behaviour is occurring?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems as though the conditions inside the parentheses don't need the curly braces. At least this has fixed it for me.

```
{if (downloads:total_rows > 0 || section_2:total_rows == 1) && {section_1:total_rows} == 1}
    Content...
{/if}
```

Comment: You're still bracing `section_1:total_rows`, is that intentional?

Comment: It is intentional however the reason why is confusing me. If I remove the braces then the content does not show, if they're there the content does show. I'm not fully understanding why this is.

Comment: Might try [2.9.0](http://ellislab.com/blog/entry/expressionengine-2.9.0-released) :)

Answer (score 1):

I would try putting your variables in curly braces:

```
{if ({downloads:total_rows} > 0 || {section_2:total_rows} == 1) && {section_1:total_rows} == 1}
    Content ...
{/if}
```

You are making this an advanced conditional so you can't access your variables correctly in the conditional without the braces. I tested the code above and it works for me.

https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/a/13946/1188

Comment: For some reason this is now throwing up an error:

`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in...`

Edit: Just noticed that there is a closing curly brace rather than bracket but the error is still appearing.

Comment: I made edits to the source in my answer

Comment: So is it still throwing a syntax error?

Comment: Unfortunately so, although it's complaining about the operator now: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '>' in...`

Comment: Are the numbers you are comparing with in quotes or not?

Comment: I've taken them all out now and swapped the `>= '1'` with `> 0` as per your example.

Comment: Okay, so now I've got it working. If I use your example but remove the curly braces within the paretheses, but leave the ones following, it works fine: `{if (downloads:total_rows > 0 || section_2:total_rows == 1) && {section_1:total_rows} == 1}` Thanks for your help, it definitely got me to the answer :)